# Problems following a C++/OpenGL Tutorial (importing images)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I need to create a small game using OpenGL and C++ . I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMyj87VJRJM) tutorial to get started(my aim isn't actually to create the game but to use the code I eventually create).

I finished video 8 (the one linked) but I ran into a problem. My code crashed on the line

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageData.Width, imageData.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData.Data);
```

Wen I change the loadAndBufferImage method parameters to something random (hgsjrkbgfdkj works fine) the code doesn't crash but obviously it doesn't load any image. I'm not sure what I am getting wrong. My IDE throws a warning on the glfwReadImage line since it doesn't like variable 3 being NULL (although it runs that line perfectly).

```
glfwReadImage(fileName, &imageData, NULL);
```

I'm not sure what I missed out/am doing wrong. Can it be the image? I used one converted via the link provided in the description of the video.  The only hing I didn't do in the video was the small image importing part at around 7.40. I am using NetBeans not XCode, and I just imported the rocket.tga file in my resources folder (right click o resources folder, Add Existing Item, added image).

Here is a full copy of my GameWindow.cpp code up till now

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GameWindow.h"
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES

#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
    GLfloat positionCoordinates[3];
    GLfloat textureCoordinates[2];
} VertexData;

#define Square_Size 100

VertexData vertices[] = {
    {{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},{0.0f,0.0f}},
    {{Square_Size, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f,0.0f}},
    {{Square_Size, Square_Size, 0.0f}, {1.0f,1.0f}},
    {{0.0f, Square_Size, 0.0f}, {0.0f,1.0f}}
};

void GameWindow::setRunning(bool newRunning) {
    _running = newRunning;
}

bool GameWindow::getRunning() {
    return _running;
}

GLuint GameWindow::loadAndBufferImage(const char *fileName){
    GLFWimage imageData;
    glfwReadImage(fileName, &imageData, NULL);

    GLuint textureBufferID;

    glGenTextures(1, &textureBufferID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBufferID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageData.Width, imageData.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData.Data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glfwFreeImage(&imageData);

    return textureBufferID;
}

GameWindow::GameWindow(bool running):_running(running), _height(800), _width(800*16/9) {
    glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, _width, _height);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0,_width,0,_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), (GLvoid *) offsetof(VertexData,positionCoordinates));
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), (GLvoid *) offsetof(VertexData, textureCoordinates));

    _textureBufferID = loadAndBufferImage("rocket.tga");
}

void GameWindow::render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

void GameWindow::update() {

}
```

I am using an oldish version of GLFW I think. Around version 2.7 because I couldn't get the new ones to work. Once again, not really relevant though I think.

Comment: Are you sure that the format of the image returned by [`glfwReadImage()`](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWReference27.pdf)  is actually RGBA ? If that's not the case, remember that [`glTexImage2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) can accept one of the following formats instead of of  `GL_RGBA`:  `GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE`, `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`

Comment: Why aren't you using `imageData.Format` for the `format` parameter of your `glTexImage2D()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imageData.Format` for `format` in `glTexImage2D()`:

```
glTexImage2D
    (
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    imageData.Width,
    imageData.Height,
    0,
    imageData.Format,  // instead of GL_RGBA
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    imageData.Data
    );
```

Otherwise if `imageData.Format == GL_RGB` and you lie and say it's `GL_RGBA` instead then OpenGL will happily [read right off the end of `imageData.Data`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Causes) looking for RGBA tuples that aren't there.

Comment: Hi. That answer/change is correct. My problem is now solved.

Why didn't I use the correct syntax previously? I'll think it is a lack of experience and/or knowledge. I started this project today morning and I am still very shaky on a certain number of topics. I obviously did try and read/fix/debug etc. but I couldn't come to a conclusion. Although the tutorial is good in general, I already found some problems throughout the 8 episodes I completed. Thanks a lot for your help!! :D